find_package() of exported dependencies builds with --merge-install but not isolated
Running ubunut 22.04, ros humble from binaries.
I have written 3 packages. Two containing libraries and the third an executable. I have split the libraries just because they were semantically different. The first library A is only linked to library B. Library B shall be used in different packages, but right now only in the third package, executable C. All are very generic packages.
The gist CMakeLists.txt of A:
add_library(A
  src/A.cpp
)

add_library(A::A ALIAS A)

target_include_directories(A PUBLIC
  "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
  "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/${PROJECT_NAME}>"
)

install(
  DIRECTORY include/
  DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

install(
  TARGETS A
  EXPORT export_${PROJECT_NAME}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
)

ament_export_include_directories(
  "include/${PROJECT_NAME}"
)

ament_export_libraries(
  A
)

ament_export_targets(
  export_${PROJECT_NAME}
)

The gist CMakeLists.txt of B:
find_package(A REQUIRED)

add_library(B
  src/B.cpp
)

add_library(B::B ALIAS B)

ament_target_dependencies(B A)

target_include_directories(B PUBLIC
  "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
  "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/${PROJECT_NAME}>"
)

install(
  DIRECTORY include/
  DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

install(
  TARGETS B
  EXPORT export_${PROJECT_NAME}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
)

ament_export_include_directories(
  "include/${PROJECT_NAME}"
)

ament_export_libraries(
  B
)

ament_export_targets(
  export_${PROJECT_NAME}
)

ament_export_dependencies(
  A
)

The gist CMakeLists.txt of C:
find_package(B REQUIRED)
...

(this is where it breaks)
Everything is fine when I compile with colcon build --merge-install but when I build simply with colcon build I get the following error:
Starting >>> C                                                                                                           
--- stderr: C
CMake Error at /ws/install/B/share/B/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake:21 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindA.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by                             
  "A", but CMake did not find one.                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by                                                                                
  "A" with any of the following names:                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                         
    AConfig.cmake                                                                                                     
    A-config.cmake                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                         
  Add the installation prefix of "A" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  or set "A_DIR" to a directory containing one of the                               
  above files.  If "A" provides a separate development                             
  package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

ament_export_dependencies generates the file ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake that is supposed to append all targets, libraries, etc. to the current library macro B_LIBRARIES etc. but for some reason cmake is not able to find the singular dependency A during this appending step. However it is working when building with --merge-install. I know that this only defines the install layout and --merge-install already makes it for me easier to find things across packages, however, I believe it should work all the same, shouldn't it? The colcon documentation claims the choice lies only in constraints of path variables and catching undeclared dependencies in tests because it gives the package only access to its declared dependencies. It does make no difference whether I find_package(A) also inside of C or not, which also confirms that A is find_packageable. I am also aware of this older post, but this is not really helpful, since all the mentioned cmake functions are deprecated and have been supposedly replaced by ament_export_targets to streamline the process (as hinted by Dirk Thomas would be useful).
Anybody has any ideas why this is happening? Or even how to do it in isolated install space?
